# Best practices on Title and Description for Git feature branch to master

Tags: azure-devops, branch

In our Scrum Team, most DevOps Engineers simply merge their feature branch to master. They usually use a title like: "Merge feature US1234 toggle feature system X to master".

Description simply contains a full list of all their commits which usually contains a lot of 'fix 1', 'fix 2', 'trying 3', etc.

Work items to link contain the "Create PR" task on the Scrum Board, which seem fine.

Are there any best-practices on merging feature branch to master with Title and Decription?